# Validate Unique username using PHP preg_grep

Tags: php, validation

I use the below block of code to validate Unique username.

```
 function validateRepositoryUnique($field, $list, &$valid) {
    if ( preg_grep('/^'.preg_quote($field->value).'$/i', $list) == -1) {
       $valid = false;
       $field->valid = false;
       $field->error = '"' . $field->value . '" already exists.';
       return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Example.

```
$filed->value = "test";
$list = array('test','test1','Test');
```

However I passed "test" in $filed->value. the Boolean kept showing value `bool(true)` when i did `var_dump(validateRepositoryUnique($field, $list, &$valid));`

And whatever I have inputted "test", "abc", "a", the Boolean kept return value `bool(true)`.

My intention is when text found in array, it will return the `$valid`'s value to false and print out the error.

Apology for my bad English and my basic knowledge of PHP programming language.

Comment: Have you considered using in_array()?

Comment: I have't tried but seem it can't validation a case sensitive and a correct format that i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

preg_grep does not return -1 if it finds no results. If returns an array of what it found. You can see the output in the example below.

Notice that I somewhat rewrote your function.

```
function validateRepositoryUnique($field, $list, &$valid) {
    $preg = preg_grep('/^'.preg_quote($field->value).'$/i', $list) ;

    var_dump($preg);
    echo "\n";

    if ( count($preg) == 0 ) {
        $valid = false;
        $field->valid = false;
        $field->error = '"' . $field->value . '" already exists.';
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

$v;
$list = ['square', 'round', 'long'];
$f1 = new stdclass;

$f1->value = 'round';
$result = validateRepositoryUnique($f1, $list, $v);
var_dump($result);
echo "\n";

$f1->value = 'grass';
$result = validateRepositoryUnique($f1, $list, $v);
var_dump($result);
echo "\n";

$f1->value = 'triangle';
$result = validateRepositoryUnique($f1, $list, $v);
var_dump($result);
echo "\n";
```

Comment: Thank for explaining about preg_grep ryantxr,
i am more understand about that now; however, I tried to debug count($preg) == 0 and seem everytime it count int(0). I am not sure if there is away to return true, false.

Comment: When I ran it, I got true, false, false as expected.

Comment: yey...........you are right, ryantxr. 
you saved me. I have spent lot time on that. 
Really appreciate for your help.